# How to use Bash script to loop through two files

Tags: bash, loops

I have a file (`file_in.txt`) containing these names:

```
aphid_splitseq.1.fasta.annot.xml
aphid_splitseq.2.fasta.annot.xml
aphid_splitseq.3.fasta.annot.xml
aphid_splitseq.4.fasta.annot.xml
aphid_splitseq.5.fasta.annot.xml
```

and I have another file (`file_out.txt`) with these names:

```
aphid_splitseq_1
aphid_splitseq_2
aphid_splitseq_3
aphid_splitseq_4
aphid_splitseq_5
```

Now I want statements like this

```
java -cp *:ext/*: es.blast2go.prog.B2GAnnotPipe -in aphid_splitseq.1.fasta.annot.xml -out results/aphid_splitseq_1 -prop b2gPipe.properties -v -annot -dat
```

Basically, I want to loop through each of `file_in.txt` and `file_out.txt` and replace the values of `-in` and `-out` with `i` and `j` respectively.

I have tried it in Bash, but it doesn't seem to work:

```sh
for i in `cat file_in.txt`
    for j in `cat file_out.txt`; do
        java -cp *:ext/*: es.blast2go.prog.B2GAnnotPipe -in $i -out results/$j -prop b2gPipe.properties -v -annot -dat
    done
done
```

Comment: This should probably be merged with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725333/looping-over-pairs-of-values-in-bash but I'm hesitant to mark them as duplicates at this time.

Comment: @tripleee, I reopened this because it was closed with a duplicate that _only_ referred to arrays and not files, but many of the solutions are file-specific (and similarly, in the array case, there are many array-specific approaches).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`paste` can be helpful:

```
#!/bin/bash

paste file_in.txt file_out.txt | while read if of; do
  echo "-in $if -out $of"
done
```

*yields:*

```
-in aphid_splitseq.1.fasta.annot.xml -out aphid_splitseq_1
-in aphid_splitseq.2.fasta.annot.xml -out aphid_splitseq_2
-in aphid_splitseq.3.fasta.annot.xml -out aphid_splitseq_3
-in aphid_splitseq.4.fasta.annot.xml -out aphid_splitseq_4
-in aphid_splitseq.5.fasta.annot.xml -out aphid_splitseq_5
```

you can modify this to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: @perreal...it worked man `#!/bin/bash

paste files_in.txt files_out.txt | while read if of; do
  echo "java -cp *:ext/*: es.blast2go.prog.B2GAnnotPipe -in $if -out results/$of -prop b2gPipe.properties -v -annot -dat" 
done`

Answer (score 1):

You can use two different `read` commands inside your `while` loop's condition, reading from two different file descriptors.

```
while read -r i <&3 && read -r j <&4; do
  java es.blast2go.prog.B2GAnnotPipe \
    -in "$i" \
    -out "results/$j" \
    -prop b2gPipe.properties -v -annot -dat
done 3<file_in.txt 4<file_out.txt
```

Putting the `3<file_in.txt` after the `done` makes file descriptor 3 read from `file_in.txt` for the duration of the loop. Similarly, putting `4<file_out.txt` makes file descriptor 4 read from `file_out.txt`. Consequently, `<&3` and `<&4` can be attached to any command within the loop to cause stdin to be attached to the chosen file for the duration of that command.

Answer (score 0):

As long as *both* your lists are just repetitions of the same kind of name with successive numbers, you shouldn't iterate over files at all. Instead, just count a variable and use that in whatever command you want executed at each step. Example:

```
COUNT=1
while [ $COUNT -lt 5 ]; do
  mv inputfile$COUNT outputfile$COUNT
  let COUNT++
done
```