# for loop in shell taking input from column name of a tab delimited file

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I want to perform a iterative task on a bunch of similar files with similar partial files names contain "{$ID}". The program is running for each of the separate files manually. I wanted to write a for loop in shell to take 'ID' from a txt file and do the task. I am unable to give the input argument ID in the for loop from the values in coloumn1 of test.txt file
Eaxmple:

```
for ID in 'values in coloumn1 of test.txt file' 
  do
    file1=xyz_{$ID}.txt
    file2=abc_{$ID}.txt
    execute the defined function using file1 and file2 
    write to > out_{$ID}.txt
 done
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping over pairs of values in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725333/looping-over-pairs-of-values-in-bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the file with a `while` loop, letting `read` both input a line from the file and splitting the first column off each line.

```
while read -r ID rest; do
    ...
done < test.txt
```

If the columns are delimited by a character other than whitespace, use `IFS` to specify that single character.

```
# comma-delimited files
while IFS=, read -r ID rest; do
    ...
done < test.txt
```