# `find -name` with regex pattern and filename replacement using `cp`

Tags: regex, file, shell, cron, find

Currently I'm using the command in `cron` to make copy of `*.data` from source to target path:

```
find /source_path -name *.data -exec cp {} /target_path \;
```

The source structure is:

```
    /source_path/category1/001.data
    /source_path/category1/002.data
    /source_path/category2/003.data
    /source_path/category3/004.data
    /source_path/categorya/005.data
    /source_path/categoryb/006.data
```

After the above `cron` command, the target will contain:

```
    /target_path/001.data
    /target_path/002.data
    /target_path/003.data
    /target_path/004.data
    /target_path/005.data
    /target_path/006.data
```

I need a one-line solution to replace my current cron command, so that after execution, the target will contain:

```
    /target_path/category1_001.data
    /target_path/category1_002.data
    /target_path/category2_003.data
    /target_path/category3_004.data
    /target_path/categorya_005.data
    /target_path/categoryb_006.data
```

To append sub-directory name as a prefix of the target filename.

Thanks.

Comment: `sed -r -e 's/\/source(_path)\/(category.+)\/([0-9]+\.data)/\/target\1\/\2_\3/gm' source_file > target_file`

Comment: What does this code do?  I'm not familiar with sed, but it looks like substitution to me.  Does it traverse the source path and make copy from source to target?  Also, `category` could be anything, containing dashes, underscore, etc, not just beginning with the word category. Thanks

Comment: You got it right..It is substitution.I am assuming that these paths are in a file and changing it and saving it in another file..Do you want this or anything else?

Comment: I think you are trying to copy the files and rename it..Is it so?

Comment: Actually these are actual files and paths in the file system. That's why there was a `cp` command involved.  I need to keep the original source untouched, while making a copy of each .data file to the target path with category_name appending as filename prefix. I'm thinking if it's possible to store the matching category into a variable and then use it with the `cp` command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping over pairs of values in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725333/looping-over-pairs-of-values-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this command which only prints strings:

```
$ find /source_path -name \*.data  | while read -r filename; do printf "print version: cp %s %s\n" "${filename}" "$(printf "%s\n" "${filename}" | sed "s/^.*[/]\(category[^/]*\)[/]\(.*[.]data\)$/\/target_path\/\1_\2/")"; done
```

**find** command prints the filenames found, one per line.

**read -r filename** read one line of text and store it into **filename** variable.

**find ... | while read -r filename** all together, write a list of filenames, one per line, into the pipe. Only one filename is read at a time. For each filename read, the command into the **while** block is executed.

The **sed** command changes a pathname **/source_path/category1/001.data** into **/target_path/category1_001.data**.

I tried my best to explain the string argument of **sed** in the lines below, but if you are interresting in these topics you should read:

- [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)
- [Regular Expressions](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html)

**s/** is the search and replace sed command and it is followed with 3 elements: "s/regex pattern/replacement/flag"

**^** at the very start means, start of the line.

**.** means any one char.

***** means 0 or infinite number of the char specified just before.

[/] means one char, the char **/**. [] are used to escape **/** otherwise it is interpreted as a delimiter between **regex pattern**, **replacement**, and **flag**.

Alltogether **^.*[/]**, means a line starting with any zero or more chars. This starting sequence must end with **/**.

[^/] means one char, **^** at start means not part of the char listed. So, it means any one char except the **/**.

[abc] between [], means one char: either a either b either c.

The first **\(.*\)** encountered in the **regex pattern** can be referenced with **\1** in **replacement**. The second **\(.*\)** encountered in the **regex pattern** can be referenced with **\2** in **replacement**. etc. Without **\** escape char, **(** means a single char `(`, and the content cannot be referenced.

When done use **cp** instead to effectively copy the files:

```
find /source_path -name \*.data  | while read -r filename; do cp "${filename}" "$(printf "%s\n" "${filename}" | sed "s/^.*[/]\(category[^/]*\)[/]\(.*[.]data\)$/\/target_path\/\1_\2/")"; done
```

Comment: This solution works for me in the test run in print strings. I haven't performed the actual run yet.

I replaced `(category[^/]*\)` with `(.*[^/]*\)` to match any possible character, since the category is actually of different names.

Could you give me some quick explanation?  Is not that readable to me.

What does `while read -r filename` do and interact with `find` or `sed`?

Also the regular expression of `[/]`, `[^/]`, and also why are you escaping parenthesis?  What are the use of brackets?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanations.  All understood.  How about `^.*` at the beginning?  Is it matching zero or more non-characters or zero or more characters?  Without \ escape char, what does ( mean?  I don't recall the need for escaping parenthesis in other programming languages eg. Perl / PHP

Comment: The answer had been updated. `^.*[/]` means a line starting with zero or more chars and this char sequence ends with `/` --
`(` without the escape char `\ `, means a single char: `(`.