# How to use sed to parse and modify the result of a find?

Tags: shell, command-line, sed, find, ksh

I stumbled upon following issue: on **a single line**, I would like to alter the result of my `find` command to do a specific `cp` depending of the files I found, with a destination name that depends of the files returned by  the `find`.

Here are my files,

```
$  find jcho -name *.data
jcho/category1/001.data
jcho/category2/002.data
```

and they must be copied to

```
jcho2/category1_001.data
jcho2/category2_002.data
```

I tried this,

```
$ find . -name *.data \
-exec cp  {} ` echo {} | sed -re 's/(jcho\/)(category[0-9]*)(\/)(.*data)/jcho2\/\2_\4/' ` \;
```

but it says it want to copy to same file -- my substitution is not made; got below error:

> cp: './jcho/category1/001.data' and './jcho/category1/001.data' are
>   the same file

So I tried something with a subshell to which I give the result of the find.
This worked (a little).

```
find jcho -name *.data -exec sh -c \ 
'f="${0}"; d=$(echo ${f} | sed -re 's/0/2/' ); cp ${f} ${d} ' {} \;
```

==>

```
find jcho -name 2*.data
jcho/category1/201.data
jcho/category2/202.data
```

### If I could include `/` in the `sed`pattern, my solution would be at hand...

But I get:

```
find jcho -name *.data -exec sh -c \
'f="${0}"; d=$(echo ${f} | sed -re 's/(jcho\/)(category[0-9]*)(\/)(.*data)/jcho2\/\2_\4/' ); cp ${f} ${d} ' {} \;
```

> -ksh: syntax error: `(' unexpected

... I tried escaping the `/` with `\`, with `\\`... not better.

idem with

```
find jcho -name *.data -exec sh -c \
'f="${0}"; d=$(echo ${f} | sed -re 's~\([^)]*\)/\([^()]*\)$~\1_\2~' ); cp ${f} ${d} ' {} \;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This is the same issue than `find -name` with regex pattern and filename replacement using `cp` [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36396401/find-name-with-regex-pattern-and-filename-replacement-using-cp)

Check the answer there.

Comment: No, it is more specific. I tried answering it differently, but could not. My question ask a solution with **sed**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **(** and **)** need to be escaped to be referenced later.

The **/** must be escaped with **[/]** in regex pattern, or with **\/** in the replacement part.

You could try the command-line below:

```
$ find jcho -name \*.data | sed -n '
{
h
s/^\(.*\)[/]\(category[^/]*\)[/]\(.*[.]data\)$/\12\/\2_\3/
H
x
s/\n/ /
p
}' | xargs -L 1 cp
```

This is working with the example provided but there will be issues if pathnames or filenames contain special chars: \n " ' space.

There are famous pages to read on these topics:

- [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)
- [Regular Expressions](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html)

Let see how sed will handle each filename read from the pipe.

0- **-n** option instructs sed to not print lines except when **p** is used.

1- jcho/category1/001.data is read from the pipe and it is stored in the pattern buffer.

```
pattern buffer = jcho/category1/001.data
```

2- **h** overwrites the content of the hold buffer with a copy of pattern buffer.

```
hold buffer = jcho/category1/001.data
```

3- the first **s** changes the content of the pattern buffer

```
pattern buffer = jcho2/category1_001.data
```

4- **H** adds pattern buffer to hold buffer

```
hold buffer = jcho/category1/001.data
jcho2/category1_001.data
```

5- **x** exchanges buffers content

```
pattern buffer = jcho/category1/001.data
jcho2/category1_001.data
```

6- the last **s** command replaces '\n' with ' ' in the pattern buffer

```
pattern buffer = jcho/category1/001.data jcho2/category1_001.data
```

7- **p** prints the current pattern buffer.

8- End of the block: return to 1 and work with next filename found.

Comment: Thanks Jay, but I am trying to do it the `sed` way with a subscript - without a loop.

Comment: @J.Chomel the answer had been updated. Let me know your remarks.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. I guess I will have hard time with sed and understanding the `h`, `H`, `x`, `p`you used there.

Comment: @J.Chomel the answer had been updated, see the new sectino at the bottom. The letters are described.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `sed` with an alternative delimiter `~`:

```
find jcho -name '*.data' | 
while read -r f; do cp "$f" "$(echo "$f" | sed 's~\([^)]*\)/\([^()]*\)$~\1_\2~')"; done
```

With your `find` output it will give:

```
jcho/category1_001.data
jcho/category2_002.data
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still get `-ksh: syntax error: `)' unexpected`

Comment: Why `ksh`? You tagged question as `bash` and should use `bash` only.

Comment: Sorry about this. I retagged it.

Comment: `sed` remains same across `bash` or `ksh` so this is something else. Can you tell me what is full command you're trying?

Answer (score 1):

probably there is an easier way than this, but with bash basename/dirname combination you can achieve the same

```
for f in $(find ...); do cp $f $(echo $(dirname $f)"_"$(basename $f)); done
```

without getting into string manipulation with regex matching.

Comment: I tried this way but `dirname` is not the right destination. It is a different path I want to copy to: `jcho2`.