# Download and change filename to a list of urls in a txt file

Tags: unix, command-line, wget

Let's say I have a .txt file where I have a list of image links that I want to download.
exaple:

```
image.jpg
image2.jpg
image3.jpg
```

I use: `cat images.txt | xargs wget` and it works just fine

What I want to do now is to provide another .txt file with the following format:

```
some_id1:image.jpg
some_id2:image2.jpg
some_id3:image3.jpg
```

What I want to do is to split each line in the ':' , download the link to the right, and change the downloaded file-name with the id provided to the left.

I want to somehow use `wget image.jpg -O some_id1.jpg`

So the output will be:

```
some_id1.jpg
some_id2.jpg
some_id3.jpg
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping over pairs of values in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725333/looping-over-pairs-of-values-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

My goto for such tasks is awk:

```
while read line; do lfn=`echo "$line" | awk -F":" '{ print $1".jpg" }'` ; rfn=`echo "$line" | awk -F":" '{ print $2 }'` ; wget $rfn -O $lfn ; done < images.txt
```

This presumes, of course, all the local file names should have the **.jpg** extension.