# Linux use a filename to derive parameters from

Tags: linux, bash, ffmpeg, sh

I am using *raspbian* for a project.

Here is my situation.  I'm creating three files:

1. a *wav* file with a filename format of *[date_and_timestamp].wav*.
2. an *avi* file with a filename format of *[date_and_timestamp].avi*.
3. a file with the name *marker_[date_and_timestamp]*

The value of *[date_and_timestamp]* is consistent across all three files.

What I want to do is look for all files starting with *marker_*, get the *[date_and_timestamp]* portion and use it to pass as a parameter to `ffmpeg` to combine the two files (i.e. ending up with a command that looks like

```
ffmpeg -i /home/motion/[date_and_timestamp].avi -i /home/motion/[date_and_timestamp].wav /home/motion/[date_and_timestamp].mp4
```

Given how powerful `sh` is, I know there will be a way, but I am far to n00bish to know what it is.

The square brackets are there for clarity.  They do not appear in the filenames.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping over pairs of values in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725333/looping-over-pairs-of-values-in-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for something like this.

```
for marker in marker_*; do
    ffmpeg -i "${marker#marker_}.avi" -i "${marker#marker_}.wav" "${marker#marker_}.mp4"
done
```

Run it in the correct directory and you won't have to hard-code the path names in the `ffmpeg` command.

The notation `${variable#prefix}` yields the value of `variable` with  `prefix` removed if present.  There is a similar construct with `%` to remove a suffix.

Comment: This is epic.  I was attempting to do it with awk -> an array, then iterating the array.  Your approach is much more elegant.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -l marker_* | awk -F[ '{ system("ffmpeg -i /home/motion/["$2".avi -i /home/motion/["$2".wav /home/motion/["$2".mp4") }'
```

This will list all files beginning with marker_ and pass this to awk, extracting the date_and_timestamp ($2 delimited by [) and then use this to pass the date to the awk system function and form a command to be executed. Place particular attention to the quotation marks when building a command to be used with the system function.

Comment: [Don¨t parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) -- it's not doing anything useful, the shell already expands the wildcard.  `printf "%s\n" marker_*` would be a slightly more robust and correct way to drive the pipeline, but still doesn't correctly handle file names which contain newlines.