# Bash Loop with outer and inner array

Tags: bash, loops

How to add another array like the output below?

I am using while loop to read the file

```
while read i
do
  echo "outer $i"
done < ./aaaaa
```

First Array (Content inside my file aaaaa)

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Second Array

```
1
2
3
```

The Output I want

```
abc1
def2
ghi3
```

Is this called multi-dimension array?

Thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop over pairs of values in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725333/looping-over-pairs-of-values-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

Use paste:

```
$ paste -d "" aaaaa bbbbb
abc1
def2
ghi3
```