# Bash combining two for loops

Tags: bash, for-loop

Im trying to create a dynamic cronjob which executes a PHP script which needs a DB argument for specific directorys.

The Output should look like this:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/test.php db_test
```

I got following:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    DIR="/var/www/html/*"
    PHP="/usr/bin/php"
    ACCOUNTS=$(ls -d $DIR)
    DBPREFIX="db_"
    DB=$( find /var/www/html/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | awk -F'/' '{print $5}' )

    for CUSTOMER in $ACCOUNTS
    do
            echo $PHP $CUSTOMER $DBPREFIX$DB
    done
```

This outputs following:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/test.php db_test test2 test3 test4
```

The Problem is that the DBPREFIX and DB vars need also to go trough a loop so that i get for every single db a complete command.

How am I able to do so?

Comment: Don't use uppercase for your private variables; uppercase variable names are reserved for system use.

Comment: And hard-coding a path to PHP is just silly. Amend the `PATH` if you have to, but allow your users to override the system location if they need to (good for testing, for example!)

Comment: Annnnd [don't use `ls` in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: thanks for the info

Comment: Probably you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725333/looping-over-pairs-of-values-in-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for something like

```
for dir in /var/www/html/*/; do
    base=${dir#/var/www/html/}
    db=${base%/}
    echo php "$db" "db_$db"   # or maybe php "${dir%/}" "db_$db"?
done
```

You could probably use something like `find -printf "..."` to accomplish much the same thing, but the `-printf` option to `find` is a GNU extension.

Comment: Thank you very much thats what I was searching for. Could you explain what the var base and db are doing?

Comment: I'm discarding the directory name with `${var#prefixtoremove}` and the trailing slash with `${var%suffixtoremove}`.

Comment: Read about [parameter expansions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal) for further explanation.