# Concatenate files that match a string in Bash

Tags: bash, cat

I have two directories (cofactors and set) and I need to concatenate the files that match a string on their names. For example, for file names that contains "aloha" and "boo" I would like to do this:

```
cat cofactors/aloha_12345.txt set/aloha_clean.txt >> aloha_12345.txt
cat cofactors/boo_5675.txt set/boo_7890.txt >> boo_5675.txt
```

I've been testing with some loops but can't get it right:

```
for c in set/*.pdb; do echo $c; if awk -F '[/_]' '{print $2}' in cofactors/*.pdb then echo cofactors/*.pdb; done
```

Comment: what if there one file `cofactors/aloha_12345.txt` and 2 files `set/aloha_clean.txt` , `set/aloha_other.txt` ?

Comment: Just edited it. I'm looking for strings on the file name.

Comment: In this case there is only one file in set/ and one in cofactors/. But if there are more files I wish to concatenate all of them if they match a string on the file name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725333/looping-over-pairs-of-values-in-bash

Comment: Your specification is not 100% complete. 1) how do you chose the name of the output file? 2) in what order to you want to concatenate the matching files? 3) when you write *file names that contains "`aloha`"* do you mean *file names that **start** with "`aloha`"* or can "`aloha`" match at any position in the file name?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this algorithm can help:

- for each `$file` in `cofactors`
- take the `prefix` of the filename before the first `_`
- concatenate the file and `set/${prefix}_*` to `$file`

Like this:

```
shopt -s nullglob

for f in cofactors/*; do
    basename=${f##*/}
    prefix=${basename%%_*}
    cat "$f" "set/${prefix}_"* > "$basename"
done
```

(Thanks [@socowi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6770384/socowi) for the improvements!)

Comment: I think you meant to glob the files in `set/`, so the last star shouldn't be quoted. It might also be helpful to enable `shopt -s nullglob` for cases when there are no matching files in `set/`.