# Is there a way to find repeated patterns in numbered strings?

Tags: awk

I have a question to ask. I research this but I couldn't find an answer.

I want to know if it is possible to execute a command or script to read a list of numbered strings and find a minimum of two or more repeated patterns on the same line.

For example, here is a sample list

```
1 5 3 1
6 7 9 4
1 7 5 2
4 6 1 5
1 0 7 3
```

In lines 1,3, and 4 the patterns of 1 and 5 are found.

Is there a way to find these patterns without me telling what numbers to look for, eg

```
awk '/1/ && /5/' file
```

Thanks, I appreciate any comments or feedback if it is not possible.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. What's a *"numbered string"* please? How is *"a minimum of two or more"* different from *"two or more"*? And *"repeated patterns on the same line"*... the same line as what? Thank you. Also, should we be finding 1 and 7 on lines 3 and 5, or not?

Comment: Are the numbers always single digits, or could `73` or `1874` occur somewhere? Are there always exactly 4 columns?

Comment: Should `3` and `1` in line 1 be matched with `1` and `3` in the last line?

Comment: 2nd and 4th lines have 2 common elements as well.

Comment: Does the order of the numbers matter? I mean would line 4 still be considered a match for the pattern `1 5` if it contained `4 6 5 1` instead of `4 6 1 5`? Are line 2 and line 4 not considered to have matching "patterns" because line 2 contains `6 4` while line 4 contains `4 6`, i.e. the wrong order?

Answer (score 0):

not fully understand the request but this script can be a basis for a follow up.

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
          {for(j=1;j<NR;j++) 
             if((j,$i) in a) 
               {c[NR,j]++; v[NR,j]=v[NR,j] FS $i} 
           a[NR,$i]}} 
   END {for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) 
          for(j=i+1; j<=NR; j++) 
            if(c[j,i]>1) print "("i","j"):" v[j,i]}' file

(1,3): 1 5
(1,4): 1 5
(1,5): 1 3
(2,4): 4 6
(3,4): 1 5
(3,5): 1 7
```

prints the line indices with common elements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the order of the numbers in each line matters, here's a generic way to get combinations of some number (dictated by the variable `r` below) of fields using GNU awk for arrays of arrays, `length(array)`, and `sorted_in`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
###################
# Calculate all combinations of a set of strings, see
# https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#AWK
###################

function get_combs(A,B, i,n,comb) {
    ## Default value for r is to choose 2 from pool of all elements in A.
    ## Can alternatively be set on the command line:-
    ##    awk -v r=<number of items being chosen> -f <scriptname>
    n = length(A)
    if (r=="") r = 2

    comb = ""
    for (i=1; i <= r; i++) { ## First combination of items:
        indices[i] = i
        comb = (i>1 ? comb OFS : "") A[indices[i]]
    }
    B[comb]

    ## While 1st item is less than its maximum permitted value...
    while (indices[1] < n - r + 1) {
        ## loop backwards through all items in the previous
        ## combination of items until an item is found that is
        ## less than its maximum permitted value:
        for (i = r; i >= 1; i--) {
            ## If the equivalently positioned item in the
            ## previous combination of items is less than its
            ## maximum permitted value...
            if (indices[i] < n - r + i) {
                ## increment the current item by 1:
                indices[i]++
                ## Save the current position-index for use
                ## outside this "for" loop:
                p = i
                break
            }
        }
        ## Put consecutive numbers in the remainder of the array,
        ## counting up from position-index p.
        for (i = p + 1; i <= r; i++) indices[i] = indices[i - 1] + 1

        ## Print the current combination of items:
        comb = ""
        for (i=1; i <= r; i++) {
            comb = (i>1 ? comb OFS : "") A[indices[i]]
        }
        B[comb]
    }
}

# Input should be a list of strings
{
    split($0,A)
    delete B
    get_combs(A,B)
    for (comb in B) {
        combs[comb][NR]
    }
    lines[NR] = $0
}

END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    for (comb in combs) {
        if ( length(combs[comb]) > 1 ) {
            print comb, "is in lines:"
            PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
            for (lineNr in combs[comb]) {
                print "\t" lineNr ":", lines[lineNr]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1 3 is in lines:
        1: 1 5 3 1
        5: 1 0 7 3
1 5 is in lines:
        1: 1 5 3 1
        3: 1 7 5 2
        4: 4 6 1 5
1 7 is in lines:
        3: 1 7 5 2
        5: 1 0 7 3
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56916316/1745001 for more information.