# Select any combination of words from file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, cut

I have a file like this:

```
one two three four five six seven eight nine ten
```

And would like to use sed/grep/awk/cut whatever to get all three words combinations from that file, so the result of the example would be:

```
one two three
two three four
three four five
four five six
five six seven
six seven eight
seven eight nine
eight nine ten
```

Can this be done with grep? Do I need a loop?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question which is highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: I don't think it can be done with `grep`, I would use `awk`. yes you probably will need a loop.

Comment: None of these tools work with both lookarounds and groups in regex. You can do it with Perl.

Comment: This is a one-liner awk. Take a time to read a [simple awk tutorial](https://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~dholland/computers/awk.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56916316/1745001 if you **really** wanted to `get all three words combinations` (which you don't but maybe someone coming across this question in future will). For what you want all you need is:

```
$ awk '{for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) print $(i-2), $(i-1), $i}' file
one two three
two three four
three four five
four five six
five six seven
six seven eight
seven eight nine
eight nine ten
```