# how can I loop over all subsets of an array?

Tags: awk

given an array

```
  a[1]=10,a[2]=20,a[3]=30
```

anyone got an iterator that runs over all subsets. for example:

```
   function show(lst) { print ""; for(i in lst ) print(i,lst[i]) }
```

e.g.

```
  forsubs("show", a)  ==>
```

10

20

30

40

10, 20

10,30

20,30

10,20,30

Comment: Depending on your milage and language of choice - there are several answers on SO for same topic. Look for "algorithm combinations". See f.ex `https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89419/algorithm-wanted-enumerate-all-subsets-of-a-set-in-order-of-increasing-sums`  

Btw, your "40" is a little out of place ?

Comment: ur correct: 40 is wrong. good catch!

Comment: This same question is posted on usenet in [comp.lang.awk](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.awk/c/ghaL8cF9as8/m/ZwnIxhVZCAAJ) where someone pointed out what's being asked for is actually a "Power Set" and has a solution at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Power_set#AWK.

Answer (score 4):

using the binary counter trick

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{n=split("10 20 30",a); 
             for(i=0;i<2^n;i++) 
               {printf "{"; 
                for(j=0;j<n;j++) printf "%s", and(i,2^j)?" "a[j+1]:""; 
                print " }"}}'
{ }
{ 10 }
{ 20 }
{ 10 20 }
{ 30 }
{ 10 30 }
{ 20 30 }
{ 10 20 30 }
```

Comment: very nice solution!

Comment: I offer a very small extension to @karakfa's excellent solution, below.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the same code as @karakfa, but storing to an array

```
# subs.awk
function push(a,x) { a[length(a)+1] = x }

function subs(a,b,  n,i,j) {
   n = length(a)
   for(i=1;i<2^n;i++) {
      b[i]["\\"]
      delete b[i]["\\"]
      for(j=0;j<n;j++) 
        if(and(i,2^j))
           push(b[i], a[j+1]) }}

function demo(  a,b,i,j) {
  split("a b c d",a," ") 
  subs(a,b)
  for(i in b) {
    for(j in b[i]) printf(" " b[i][j])
     print ""}}

BEGIN { demo() }
```

Output:

```
gawk -f subs.awk 
a
b
a b
c
a c
b c
a b c
d
a d
b d
a b d 
c d
a c d
b c d 
a b c d
```

Answer (score 2):

Reusing  the `get_combs()` function from [how-would-i-loop-over-pairs-of-values-without-repetition-in-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56911991/how-would-i-loop-over-pairs-of-values-without-repetition-in-bash)

```
$ cat subsets.awk
###################
# Calculate all combinations of a set of strings, see
# https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#AWK
###################

function get_combs(A,B, i,n,comb) {
    ## Default value for r is to choose 2 from pool of all elements in A.
    ## Can alternatively be set on the command line:-
    ##    awk -v r=<number of items being chosen> -f <scriptname>
    n = length(A)
    if (r=="") r = 2

    comb = ""
    for (i=1; i <= r; i++) { ## First combination of items:
        indices[i] = i
        comb = (i>1 ? comb OFS : "") A[indices[i]]
    }
    B[comb]

    ## While 1st item is less than its maximum permitted value...
    while (indices[1] < n - r + 1) {
        ## loop backwards through all items in the previous
        ## combination of items until an item is found that is
        ## less than its maximum permitted value:
        for (i = r; i >= 1; i--) {
            ## If the equivalently positioned item in the
            ## previous combination of items is less than its
            ## maximum permitted value...
            if (indices[i] < n - r + i) {
                ## increment the current item by 1:
                indices[i]++
                ## Save the current position-index for use
                ## outside this "for" loop:
                p = i
                break
            }
        }

        ## Put consecutive numbers in the remainder of the array,
        ## counting up from position-index p.
        for (i = p + 1; i <= r; i++) indices[i] = indices[i - 1] + 1

        ## Print the current combination of items:
        comb = ""
        for (i=1; i <= r; i++) {
            comb = (i>1 ? comb OFS : "") A[indices[i]]
        }
        B[comb]
    }
}

BEGIN {
    n = split("10 20 30",A)
    for (r=1; r<=n; r++) {
        delete B
        get_combs(A,B)
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        for (comb in B) {
            print comb
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f subsets.awk
10
20
30
10 20
10 30
20 30
10 20 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there anyway to

- keep simplicity of @karakfa's approach...
- ... while also but adding in how   @EdMorton's code generates things smallest to largest?

I tried   change @karakfa's inner loops but that did not work.

What I
could do (which I don't like) is to add a post-processor that sorts
on size (see below).

But anyone got a more elegant method?

```
 # subs.awk
function push(a,x) { a[length(a)+1] = x }

function subs(a,b,  m,n,i,j) {
   n = length(a)
   for(i=1;i<=2^n ;i++) {
     b[i][0]
     delete b[i][0]
     for(j=0;j<n;j++) 
       if(and(i,2^j))
          push(b[i], a[j+1]); }}
 
function sizeSort(_,a,__,b,  l1,l2) {
  l1=length(a)
  l2=length(b)
  return l1==l2 ? 0 : (l1<l2 ? -1 : 1) }

function demo(  a,b,i,j,n) {
  split("10 20 30 40",a," ") 
  subs(a,b)
  n=asort(b,c,"sizeSort")
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printl(c[i]) }

function printl(a,   i){
  for(i in a) printf(" " a[i])
  print "" }

BEGIN { demo() }
```

Output:

```
% gawk -f subs.awk 

 20
 30
 10
 40
 20 30
 10 20
 10 40
 20 40
 30 40
 10 30
 10 20 30
 10 30 40
 20 30 40
 10 20 40
 10 20 30 40
```

Comment: any of course, to really speed this up, pre-compute and. cache the indexes of all solutions of size n=1, n=2, n=3 etc (which would make any makes subsequent reasoning "over all subsets" just a quick table look up)