# How to generate all possible combinations of lines in a file using Bash?

Tags: bash, recursion, awk, split, combinations

I have the file "test.txt" (arbitrary number of lines):

```
$ cat test.txt
A
B
C
```

I would like to find a bash code to generate all possible combinations with **n** elements, where **n** >= 2, starting with all elements (i.e. number of lines, **X**), so that n = X, n = X-1, n = X-2, n = X-3, ..., n = 2, which in the case above would be:

```
A,B,C
A,B
A,C
B,C
```

Any suggestions?
Many thanks!

Comment: what (code) have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you have an arbitrary number of lines, or always 3 lines?

Comment: Any number of lines, n > 2 . I'm editing the question.

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reusing the `get_combs()` function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56916316/1745001:

```
$ cat tst.awk
###################
# Calculate all combinations of a set of strings, see
# https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#AWK
###################

function get_combs(A,B, i,n,comb) {
    ## Default value for r is to choose 2 from pool of all elements in A.
    ## Can alternatively be set on the command line:-
    ##    awk -v r=<number of items being chosen> -f <scriptname>
    n = length(A)
    if (r=="") r = 2

    comb = ""
    for (i=1; i <= r; i++) { ## First combination of items:
        indices[i] = i
        comb = (i>1 ? comb OFS : "") A[indices[i]]
    }
    B[comb]

    ## While 1st item is less than its maximum permitted value...
    while (indices[1] < n - r + 1) {
        ## loop backwards through all items in the previous
        ## combination of items until an item is found that is
        ## less than its maximum permitted value:
        for (i = r; i >= 1; i--) {
            ## If the equivalently positioned item in the
            ## previous combination of items is less than its
            ## maximum permitted value...
            if (indices[i] < n - r + i) {
                ## increment the current item by 1:
                indices[i]++
                ## Save the current position-index for use
                ## outside this "for" loop:
                p = i
                break}}
        ## Put consecutive numbers in the remainder of the array,
        ## counting up from position-index p.
        for (i = p + 1; i <= r; i++) indices[i] = indices[i - 1] + 1

        ## Print the current combination of items:
        comb = ""
        for (i=1; i <= r; i++) {
            comb = (i>1 ? comb OFS : "") A[indices[i]]
        }
        B[comb]
    }
}

# Input should be a list of strings
{ A[NR] = $0 }
END {
    OFS = ","
    for (r=NR; r>=2; r--) {
        delete B
        get_combs(A,B)
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        for (comb in B) {
            print comb
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk test.txt
A,B,C
A,B
A,C
B,C
```

Comment: Extremely useful! Any way for keeping only combinations of two elements and discarding bigger ones?

Comment: @jgarces Anythings possible - ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- the string `A,B,C` is considered to be equivalent to `A,C,B`, `B,A,C`, `B,C,A`, `C,A,B` and `C,B,A` (ie, we only need to generate one of these 6 combinations)

One idea for generating a list of combinations ...

- we'll load lines into an array
- for each item in the array we'll start a new set of output strings
- make recursive calls to append the **next array item** to our output string
- as we're appending array items to the output we'll go ahead and print each string that consists of 2 or more array items
- this is more of a tail recursion method which should eliminate the generation of duplicates (`A,B,C` vs the other 5 equivalent patterns) and/or or the need to rollback "already seen' combos

One `awk` idea for implementing this logic:

```
awk '

# input params are current output string, current arr[] index, and current output length (ie, number of fields)
# parameter "i" will be treated as a local variable

function combo(output, j, combo_length,  i) {

    if ( combo_length >= 2)           # print any combination with a length >= 2
       print output

    for (i=j+1; i<=n; i++)            # loop through "rest" of array entries for next field in output
        combo(output "," arr[i], i, combo_length+1 )
}

    { arr[NR]=$1 }                     # load fields into array "arr[]"

END { n=length(arr)

      for (i=1; i<=n; i++)             # for each arr[i] start a new set of combos starting with arr[i]
          combo(arr[i],i,1)
    }
' test.txt
```

This generates:

```
A,B
A,B,C
A,B,C,D
A,B,D
A,C
A,C,D
A,D
B,C
B,C,D
B,D
C,D
```

If we want to sort based on number of fields and then the output string we can make the following change:

- change `print output` to `print combo_length, output` and then ...
- pipe the `awk` output through `sort | cut` (we'll borrow glenn's code here)

This generates:

```
$ awk ' ... print combo_length,output ...' test.txt |  sort -k1,1nr -k2 | cut -d" " -f2-

A,B,C,D
A,B,C
A,B,D
A,C,D
B,C,D
A,B
A,C
A,D
B,C
B,D
C,D
```

---

---

For a 20-line `test.txt` ( letters `A` to `T`) with the output dumped to file `test.out`:

```
$ time awk '...' test.txt > test.out

real    0m1.420s
user    0m1.279s
sys     0m0.139s

$ wc -l test.out
 1048555  2097110 23685256 test.out

$ time awk '...' test.txt | sort ... | cut ... > test.out

real    0m3.456s
user    0m3.493s
sys     0m0.185s

$ wc test.out
 1048555  1048555 20971480 test.out
```

Answer (score 1):

with the binary counter trick to iterate all subsets...

```
$ awk '{a[NR]=$1}
   END {for(i=0;i<2^NR;i++)
          {printf "{";
           for(j=0;j<NR;j++) printf "%s", and(i,2^j)?FS a[j+1]:"";
           print " }"}}' file


{ }
{ A }
{ B }
{ A B }
{ C }
{ A C }
{ B C }
{ A B C }
{ D }
{ A D }
{ B D }
{ A B D }
{ C D }
{ A C D }
{ B C D }
{ A B C D }
```

In the desired format, pipe to another awk to filter n<2 elements

```
awk -v FS=, '{a[NR]=$1}
         END {for(i=0;i<2^NR;i++)
             {s=""; 
              for(j=0;j<NR;j++) 
                {e=and(i,2^j); 
                 printf "%s", e?s a[j+1]:""; if(e)s=FS}
              print comb}}' file | 
awk -F, 'NF>1'


A,B
A,C
B,C
A,B,C
A,D
B,D
A,B,D
C,D
A,C,D
B,C,D
A,B,C,D
```

### How does it work?

All combinations are equivalent to all subsets of the given elements.  This in turn can be enumerated (tagged) with 0..2^n-1.
If we represent the enumeration counter in binary, each position bit can be mapped to an element of the full set.  So when running the enumeration on all subsets we can create a particular subset with the elements where the corresponding bit is set for a given tag.

For example for a 3 element initial set {A,B,C}.  We have the enumeration

```
0 0 0   -> no elements, empty subset  -> { }
0 0 1   -> A bit is set               -> { A }
0 1 0   -> B bit is set               -> { B }
0 1 1   -> Both A and B bits are set  -> { A B }
... etc
```

the rest is just formatting.

This method is good for generating all combinations, for various constraints which will reduce the choices (e.g. exactly 3 elements) this is not very efficient.  Also, there is an upper bound for N, due to 2^N.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to get each possible combination of all the lines:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$0]; next } { for (i in a) print i, $0 }' test.txt test.txt
```

Then, we can use [`split`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) to write each line into a seperate file:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$0]; next } { for (i in a) print i, $0 }' test.txt test.txt > tmp.txt
split -l 1 -d tmp.txt "test-"
rm tmp.txt
```

Example on my local machine:

```
$
$ cat test.txt
A
B
C
$
$ awk 'NR==FNR { a[$0]; next } { for (i in a) print i, $0 }' test.txt test.txt > tmp.txt
$ split -l 1 -d tmp.txt "test-"
$ rm tmp.txt
$
$ tail -n +1 *
==> test-00 <==
A A

==> test-01 <==
B A

==> test-02 <==
C A

==> test-03 <==
A B

==> test-04 <==
B B

==> test-05 <==
C B

==> test-06 <==
A C

==> test-07 <==
B C

==> test-08 <==
C C

==> test.txt <==
A
B
C
$
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I think it's almost there. Perhaps I wasn't very clear. 1) I don't want the output files to contain identical elements (e.g. (A,A), (B,B), etc) and 2) I want it to generate combinations of n elements, where n >= 2, including the full set (n=X), then n=X-1, n=X-2, etc until n = 2. Perhaps I'm just being lazy.. could do a work around on your reply..

Comment: And how to remove identical combinations but differing order? (ie, AB would be the same as BA). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A bash recursive function: this won't be the fastest solution

```sh
all_combinations() {
    (($# == 0)) && return
    (IFS=,; echo "$*")
    local i x
    for ((i=0; i<$#; i++)); do 
        x=("$@")
        unset 'x[i]'
        "${FUNCNAME[0]}" "${x[@]}"
    done
}

combinations() {
    all_combinations "$@" |
      grep , |                      # at least 2 element
      sort -u |                     # remove duplicates
      while IFS= read -r line; do   # print number of elements
          printf '%d\t%s\n' \
            $(commas=${line//[^,]/}; echo ${#commas}) \
            "$line"
      done |
      sort -k1,1nr -k2 |            # sort by num + line
      cut -f2-                      # remove num
}

mapfile -t lines < test.txt
combinations "${lines[@]}"
```

if test.txt contains 4 lines, this produces

```
A,B,C,D
A,B,C
A,B,D
A,C,D
B,C,D
A,B
A,C
A,D
B,C
B,D
C,D
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works like a charm, and will do the job as the number of lines will rarely exceed 5 - above that it gets very slow indeed.