# Generate all possible dual combinations of file [BASH]

Tags: bash, awk, combinations

I'm trying to generate all possible *dual* combinations (in my case, of files) with the following script taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68187269/7580614):

```
function get_combs(A,B, i,n,comb) {
    n = length(A)
    if (r=="") r = 2

    comb = ""
    for (i=1; i <= r; i++) {
        indices[i] = i
        comb = (i>1 ? comb OFS : "") A[indices[i]]
    }
    B[comb]

    while (indices[1] < n - r + 1) {
        for (i = r; i >= 1; i--) {
            if (indices[i] < n - r + i) {
                indices[i]++
                  p = i
                break}}
        for (i = p + 1; i <= r; i++) indices[i] = indices[i - 1] + 1

        comb = ""
        for (i=1; i <= r; i++) {
            comb = (i>1 ? comb OFS : "") A[indices[i]]
        }
        B[comb]
    }
}

{ A[NR] = $0 }
END {
    OFS = "\t"
    for (r=NR; r>=2; r--) {
        delete B
        get_combs(A,B)
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        for (comb in B) {
            print comb
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works nice but it's generating all combos, not only the dual ones:

```
$ awk -f combos.awk <(ls *pileup)
348-34_control_MO.sorted.bam.pileup 577_MO.sorted.bam.pileup    822_MO1.sorted.bam.pileup
348-34_control_MO.sorted.bam.pileup 577_MO.sorted.bam.pileup
348-34_control_MO.sorted.bam.pileup 822_MO1.sorted.bam.pileup
577_MO.sorted.bam.pileup    822_MO1.sorted.bam.pileup
```

I'd like something like that:

```
348-34_control_MO.sorted.bam.pileup 577_MO.sorted.bam.pileup
348-34_control_MO.sorted.bam.pileup 822_MO1.sorted.bam.pileup
577_MO.sorted.bam.pileup    822_MO1.sorted.bam.pileup
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and the expected output given that input. Showing the input as whatever `<(ls *pileup)` outputs is not useful as we can't copy/paste whatever that unshown output on your computer is to test with. Make it as simple as possible for us to help you - just some simple, flat text like A, B, C, or similar for the input/output, no need for lengthy strings like `348-34_control_MO.sorted.bam.pileup`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample input to simulate `ls *pileup`:

```
$ cat ls.out
577_MO.sorted.bam.pileup
348-34_control_MO.sorted.bam.pileup
822_MO1.sorted.bam.pileup
```

One `awk` approach:

```
awk '
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
      { A[NR]=$0 }
END   { for (i=1;i<NR;i++) 
            for (j=i+1;j<=NR;j++) 
                print A[i],A[j]
      }
' <(sort -V ls.out)
```

**NOTE:** in OP's case the `sort -V ls.out` would be replaced with `ls *pileup | sort -V` (or whatever `sort` options are appropriate)

This generates:

```
348-34_control_MO.sorted.bam.pileup     577_MO.sorted.bam.pileup
348-34_control_MO.sorted.bam.pileup     822_MO1.sorted.bam.pileup
577_MO.sorted.bam.pileup        822_MO1.sorted.bam.pileup
```

Comment: Thanks a lot (especially for the patience about missing examples or inputs)!