# How to make combinations of a periodic sequence

Tags: python, bash

I have a DNA sequence, like  `CCG ACG GCA CTG GGC CAG TTG`.

I want to make all possible combinations of this sequence without changing the sequence of each sub-set (say CCG should be CCG only).
For example,
The modified sequence may be

```
ACG CCG GCA CTG GGC CAG TTG   # Here the first two sub-sets are interchanged.
GCA ACG CCG CTG GGC CAG TTG   # Here the first and third sub-sets are interchanged.
```

Is there any easy way to use a shell script or a python code that can give me all the possible combinations?

In each possible combination, it will cover these seven sub-sets.

Comment: What is the expected output in case of repeated triplets, e.g. `ACG ACG`?

Comment: I need all possible combinations of these triplets.

Comment: Depending on how you want to handle duplicates, `premutations` from Python's `itertools` may do what you want.

Comment: Okay, let me explain in some more detail. Maybe I missed it in the main question. In each combination, the possible combination will cover these seven sub-sets.

Comment: When you say "combinations" - you mean "permutations", right? All "combinations" would just be your input line printed once.

Comment: Thank you Sir, the question is already answered well. I have voted for your answer as well as a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use premuations from itertools for example:

```py
import itertools

dna = "CCG ACG GCA CTG GGC CAG TTG"
dna = dna.split()

for combination in itertools.permutations(dna):
    print(combination)
```

I first did a split() which creates an array of the original dna string separated by spaces like so:

```py
['CCG', 'ACG', 'GCA', 'CTG', 'GGC', 'CAG', 'TTG']
```

Then use itertools.permutation() which would return all the combinations of this array's indices.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ankita, it gave me 5040 sequences. Could you please make sure that it will not interchange any character from each sub-sets?  Like CCA to CAC.

Comment: No, it is simply rearranging the indices of the split array so no need to worry about interchanged characters.. The array does have ACG and CAG but i assume this was intentional. Also 5040 would be correct because there as 7 elements in the array and 7 factorial = 5040

Answer (score 1):

While a lot slower than the python version, a pure `bash` script that prints the permutations of its arguments:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s lastpipe

permutations() {
    if [[ $# -gt 1 ]]; then
        local -a elems=( "$@" )
        local i curr result
        for (( i = 0; i < $#; i++ )); do
            curr="${elems[i]}"
            unset "elems[i]"
            permutations "${elems[@]}" | while read -r result; do
                printf "%s %s\n" "$curr" "$result"
            done
            elems[i]="$curr"
        done
    elif [[ $# -eq 1 ]]; then
        printf "%s\n" "$1"
    fi
}

permutations "$@"
```

It just uses a simple recursive approach to calculating all permutations of a list.

```
$ bash perms.sh CCG ACG GCA CTG GGC CAG TTG
CCG ACG GCA CTG GGC CAG TTG
CCG ACG GCA CTG GGC TTG CAG
CCG ACG GCA CTG CAG GGC TTG
CCG ACG GCA CTG CAG TTG GGC
CCG ACG GCA CTG TTG GGC CAG
CCG ACG GCA CTG TTG CAG GGC
...
many more lines
...
TTG CAG GGC CTG GCA ACG CCG
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an awk that supports length(array) (should be most of them these days):

```
$ cat permutations.awk
###################
# Calculate all permutations of a set of strings, see
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm

function get_perm(A,            i, lgth, sep, str) {
    lgth = length(A)
    for (i=1; i<=lgth; i++) {
        str = str sep A[i]
        sep = " "
    }
    return str
}

function swap(A, x, y,  tmp) {
    tmp  = A[x]
    A[x] = A[y]
    A[y] = tmp
}

function generate(n, A, B,      i) {
    if (n == 1) {
        B[get_perm(A)]
    }
    else {
        for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {
            generate(n - 1, A, B)
            if ((n%2) == 0) {
                swap(A, 1, n)
            }
            else {
                swap(A, i, n)
            }
        }
    }
}

function get_perms(A,B) {
    generate(length(A), A, B)
}

###################

# Input should be a list of strings
{
    split($0,A)
    delete B
    get_perms(A,B)
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
    for (perm in B) {
        print perm
    }
}
```

```
$ echo 'CCG ACG GCA' | awk -f permutations.awk
ACG CCG GCA
ACG GCA CCG
CCG ACG GCA
CCG GCA ACG
GCA ACG CCG
GCA CCG ACG
```

The above includes a GNU-ism `PROCINFO[]` but it'll work fine in other awks too, that part will just be ignored and the output won't be sorted but you can always pipe it to `sort` if you like.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56916316/1745001 for how to get combinations too.

Answer (score 0):

if you just wanna do cartesian permutations that happens to be powers of 2, string squaring is way faster than looping :

> ```
> echo 'CCG ACG GCA CTG GGC CAG TTG' |
> ```

---

> ```
>   gawk -p- -be '
>        gsub("^| ", "\\&&", $!(NF = NF))^_ + gsub(FS,_);
>        gsub("[&][^&]+",$_); gsub("[&][^&]+",$_) + \
>        gsub("[&]",",")     + sub("^,",_) + gsub(".{52}","&\n")' ORS='\n\n' |
> ```

---

> ```
> gcat -b |gtee >( ghead >&2; echo >&2; ) | gcat - | gtail -n 30
> ```

---

```
   604      # gawk profile, created Fri Apr 28 15:54:58 2023

   605      # Rule(s)

   606       1  gsub("^| ", "\\&&", $!(NF = NF))^_ + gsub(FS,_)

   609       1  gsub("[&][^&]+", $_)

   612       1  gsub("[&][^&]+", $_) + gsub(  "[&]", ",") \ 
                     + sub("^,",  _) + gsub(".{52}", "&\n")
```

---

```
     1  &CCG&ACG&GCA&CTG&GGC&CAG&TTG

     2  &CCGCCG&CCGACG&CCGGCA&CCGCTG&CCGGGC&CCGCAG&CCGTTG&ACGCCG&ACGACG&ACGGCA&ACGCTG&ACGGGC&ACGCAG&ACGTTG&GCACCG&GCAACG&GCAGCA&GCACTG&GCAGGC&GCACAG&GCATTG&CTGCCG&CTGACG&CTGGCA&CTGCTG&CTGGGC&CTGCAG&CTGTTG&GGCCCG&GGCACG&GGCGCA&GGCCTG&GGCGGC&GGCCAG&GGCTTG&CAGCCG&CAGACG&CAGGCA&CAGCTG&CAGGGC&CAGCAG&CAGTTG&TTGCCG&TTGACG&TTGGCA&TTGCTG&TTGGGC&TTGCAG&TTGTTG

     3  CCGCCGCCGCCG,CCGCCGCCGACG,CCGCCGCCGGCA,CCGCCGCCGCTG,
     4  CCGCCGCCGGGC,CCGCCGCCGCAG,CCGCCGCCGTTG,CCGCCGACGCCG,
     5  CCGCCGACGACG,CCGCCGACGGCA,CCGCCGACGCTG,CCGCCGACGGGC,
     6  CCGCCGACGCAG,CCGCCGACGTTG,CCGCCGGCACCG,CCGCCGGCAACG,
     7  CCGCCGGCAGCA,CCGCCGGCACTG,CCGCCGGCAGGC,CCGCCGGCACAG,
     8  CCGCCGGCATTG,CCGCCGCTGCCG,CCGCCGCTGACG,CCGCCGCTGGCA,

   591  TTGTTGCCGCCG,TTGTTGCCGACG,TTGTTGCCGGCA,TTGTTGCCGCTG,
   592  TTGTTGCCGGGC,TTGTTGCCGCAG,TTGTTGCCGTTG,TTGTTGACGCCG,
   593  TTGTTGACGACG,TTGTTGACGGCA,TTGTTGACGCTG,TTGTTGACGGGC,
   594  TTGTTGACGCAG,TTGTTGACGTTG,TTGTTGGCACCG,TTGTTGGCAACG,
   595  TTGTTGGCAGCA,TTGTTGGCACTG,TTGTTGGCAGGC,TTGTTGGCACAG,
   596  TTGTTGGCATTG,TTGTTGCTGCCG,TTGTTGCTGACG,TTGTTGCTGGCA,
   597  TTGTTGCTGCTG,TTGTTGCTGGGC,TTGTTGCTGCAG,TTGTTGCTGTTG,
   598  TTGTTGGGCCCG,TTGTTGGGCACG,TTGTTGGGCGCA,TTGTTGGGCCTG,
   599  TTGTTGGGCGGC,TTGTTGGGCCAG,TTGTTGGGCTTG,TTGTTGCAGCCG,
   600  TTGTTGCAGACG,TTGTTGCAGGCA,TTGTTGCAGCTG,TTGTTGCAGGGC,
   601  TTGTTGCAGCAG,TTGTTGCAGTTG,TTGTTGTTGCCG,TTGTTGTTGACG,
   602  TTGTTGTTGGCA,TTGTTGTTGCTG,TTGTTGTTGGGC,TTGTTGTTGCAG,
   603  TTGTTGTTGTTG


   ( echo 'CCG ACG GCA CTG GGC CAG TTG' | gawk -p- -be  ORS='\n\n'; )

   0.01s user 0.01s system 78% cpu 0.015 total
```

taking **less than 20 ms** to return permutations equivalent to the **4th power of input combinations**.

even 8th power was only 0.752 secs :

```
( echo 'CCG ACG GCA CTG GGC CAG TTG' | 

mawk2  ORS='\n\n'; )  

0.41s user 0.08s system 65% cpu 0.751 total

2882398 TTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGCAGACG,TTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGCAGGCA,
2882399 TTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGCAGCTG,TTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGCAGGGC,
2882400 TTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGCAGCAG,TTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGCAGTTG,
2882401 TTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGCCG,TTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGACG,
2882402 TTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGGCA,TTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGCTG,
2882403 TTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGGGC,TTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGCAG,
2882404 TTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTG
```