# awk for loops on the associative array

Tags: awk, associative-array

The below code prints only for line **a** and **b** ignoring **c**

```
awk '{a[$0]} END {for(i in a) for(j in a) for(k in a) print i, j, k}' < <(echo -e 'a\nb\c\n')

output:
a a a
a a b
a b a
a b b
b a a
b a b
b b a
b b b
```

what to change in the above code so that line **c** comes in the output permutation?

Comment: Not reproducible: https://ideone.com/o0cCWU

Comment: @blhsing: It is reproducible, you didn't run exact command that was used by OP. Just use `awk '1' < <(echo -e 'a\nb\c\n')` and you will see same behavior.

Comment: @anubhava I now see it's a typo of `\c` that causes the behavior. Will maintain my vote to close the question since "not reproducible" and "typo" are lumped as the same closure option.

Comment: Yes that is your call but jfyi fixing the typo also won't give desired results. Just run OP's command with `< <(echo -e 'a\nb\nc\n')`

Comment: Checking the input should always be the first step to debugging undesirable output. Does `echo -e 'a\nb\c\n'` produce the output you expected? Anyway, rather than hard-coding loops, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56916316/1745001 for how to print all permutations (and combinations) of an input string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use process substitution. Just use a here-string like this:

```sh
awk '{a[$0]} END {for(i in a) for(j in a) for(k in a) print i, j, k}' <<< $'a\nb\nc'

a a a
a a b
a a c
a b a
a b b
a b c
a c a
a c b
a c c
b a a
b a b
b a c
b b a
b b b
b b c
b c a
b c b
b c c
c a a
c a b
c a c
c b a
c b b
c b c
c c a
c c b
c c c
```

Just a note that `printf` is more portable and consistent so better to use `< <(printf 'a\nb\nc\n')` instead of `echo -e`