# How to remove directories in a list from two lists?

Tags: grep, csh

I am writing a c-shell script, where I am grepping two different directories in two strings. I wanted to remove the name of the directories which are the same. I only want the unique directory among the two by leaving out the duplicate ones. I am little confused about how to do this.

There are some common directories present in sta_views and pnr_views strings. I am grepped both of them using ls -l command as seen above stored them. Now what I want to do is "first we can loop over sta_view and check if that exist in the pnr_view list and if no , then put them in a separate list , if yes , then do not do anything" Hope this helps to understand you my question. Thank You!

Please let me know the approach to do it,

```
set pnr_views = `(ls -l pnr/rep/signoff_pnr/ | grep '^d' | awk '{print $9}'\n)`
set sta_views = `(ls -l sta/rep/ | grep '^d' | grep -v common | grep -v signoff.all.SAVEDESIGN | awk '{print $9}'\n)`

foreach i ($sta_view) 
if [$i == $pnr_view] #just want to remove the list pnr_view from sta_view
then
echo ...
else
```

Here `sta_views` contains the directories that are present in `pnr_views`. How shall I remove the `pnr_views` directories from `sta_views`?

Comment: Please don't spam tags. If you need help with [tag:csh] don't use [tag:bash] (or [tag:sh] or [tag:python] or [tag:javascript] ... etc)

Comment: As an aside, [don't use `ls` in scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [avoid useless `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: For your concideration: [Top 10 Reasons not to use C Shell](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt) and [Csh programming considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/)

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the directories in the first directory, and simply check whether the same entry exists in the second.

```csh
foreach i ( pnr/rep/signoff_pnr/*/ )
  if ( -d sta/rep/"$i:h:t" ) then
    switch ("$i:h:t")
      case *'common'*:
      case *'signoff.all.SAVEDESIGN'*:
        breaksw
      default:
        echo sta/rep/"$i:h:t"
        breaksw
    endsw
  endif
end
```

The Csh variable modifier `$i:h` returns the directory name part of the file name in `$i` and the modifier `:t` returns the last element from that.

Csh is extremely fickle and thus these days rather unpopular; you might have better luck if you switch to a modern Bourne-compatible shell, especially if you are only just learning.  See also [Csh considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/) and the other links on https://www.shlomifish.org/open-source/anti/csh/. [Looping over pairs of values in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725333/looping-over-pairs-of-values-in-bash) shows how to do something similar in Bash.