# How to list a number of files with the same ending?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a list 15 files all with the ending `******_filteredSNPs.txt`.
The starred bit is individual names for each of the 15 file. How do I list all these files?

I need the output files to have the individual names at the start but with the ending clumped.

E.g.

```
cd /data/PRS/

i=$PBS_ARRAYID

file="${i}_filteredSNPs.txt"
out="${i}_clumped"


./plink \
    --bfile filesforPRS \
    --clump-p1 1 \
    --clump-r2 0.1 \
    --clump-kb 250 \
    --clump ${file} \
    --clump-snp-field ID \
    --clump-field P \
    --out ${out}
```

I am trying the above but get an error as it fails to open my input files.

Comment: What will work depends on your operating system and shell; Windows `cmd` has wildly different handling of wildcards than Unix shells, for example. There are also many incompatible Unix shells like Fish and the Csh (dysfunctional :-) family.

By the vague looks of your question, I'm guessing you are looking for the simple Bourne shell wildcard
`*_filteredSNPs.txt`
though it's not at all clear what the requirements of `--clump` are. Is this the name of an option of a command? Does it have a man page?

Comment: Merely specifying a wildcard after the option name won't work because the shell will expand the wildcard, which looks to the calling program like the first of the expanded names is the argument to `--clump` and the rest are something else, typically just file names for the command to read. Voting to close as unclear anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Please see the edited question. I want to list a number of files to one command and the output should correspond to each input file.

Comment: This requires `plink` to allow more than one `--clump` option; does it?

Comment: Or do you mean you want to run `plink` 15 times with different pairs of arguments, like `--clump one_filtered.txt` with output to `one_clumped`, then `--clump two_filtered.txt` with output to `two_clumped`, etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28725333/looping-over-pairs-of-values-in-bash

Comment: I think you can specify more than one input files but I can't seem to code how to do this when the ending for each file is the same but the start of it is different. I also want the output file to match each input file

Comment: Sounds like the proposed duplicate then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question remains unclear and probably a duplicate, but I'm guessing it's either of the following. Please follow up in a comment, or edit your question to clarify it still.

Perhaps you are looking for a way to run `plink` on each matching file separately?

```
for file in *_filteredSNPs.txt; do
    ./plink \
        --bfile filesforPRS \
        --clump-p1 1 \
        --clump-r2 0.1 \
        --clump-kb 250 \
        --clump "$file" \
        --clump-snp-field ID \
        --clump-field P \
        --out "${file%_filteredSNPs.txt}_clumped"
done
```

Notice also how double quotes (but *not* braces `{...}`) are necessary to avoid problems when handling files with unusual characters in their names; see [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)
The [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) `${file%_filteredSNPs.txt}` returns the value of the variable with the suffix after `%` removed.

This uses no Bash features, and so will work with any `sh` variant.

Or, if your `plink` command allows more than one `--clump` option, and you want to add them all into the same command line, you can just interpolate them into it.

```
# Put beginning of command into array
cmd=(./plink \
    --bfile filesforPRS \
    --clump-p1 1 \
    --clump-r2 0.1 \
    --clump-kb 250)
# Add matches to array
for file in *_filteredSNPs.txt; do
    cmd+=(--clump "$file")
done
# Then add tail of command
cmd+=(--clump-snp-field ID \
    --clump-field P \
    --out "$out")
# Finally, execute it
"${cmd[@]}"
```

If you have 15 matching files, this will add the `--clump` option 15 times, each followed by another one of the 15 file names, then run `plink` once.

Arrays are a Bash feature, so this will not  work portably with `sh`.